# Python cqlengine blobasinet alternative

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlengine

```
SELECT blobasinet(columnname) from table ;
system.blobasinet(columnname)
-------------------------------------------
192.168.97.12
192.168.96.9
```

This query will return the IP string for Blob Field

what is the cqlengine version for this query?

Answer (score 2):

CQL functions are currently not implemented in cqlengine.